# Creating a .jar file - Get "Could not find main class" even with manifest.txt WITH a carriage return

Tags: java, class, jar, program-entry-point

I'm trying to create my first jar file and I'm having trouble. I'm using the DOS to do it and my path and everything are all set up correctly.

These are the files I'm trying to include:
Bot.class
Start.class
Stop.class
Thread.class

I've created a manifest file that looks like this (it also has a carriage return at the end)

```
Main-Class: Bot
```

Here is what I'm running through the DOS

```
jar cf Bot.jar Manifest.txt Bot.class Start.class Stop.class Visit.class
```

It creates the jar successfully and but when I try and execute it, either by clicking on it or using the command prompt I get

```
Could not find the main class: Bot. Program will exit.
```

I have tried using both Bot and Bot.class in the manifest file but still get the same error. I've only tried changing the extension on the manifest file to .mf instead of .txt

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: OK, for other users: `JAR`s are ZIP folders. Open it and check everything's in there. I just spent hours trying to run a half-empty jar.

Answer (score 2):

```
jar cmf Manifest.txt Bot.jar Bot.class Start.class Stop.class Visit.class
```

The `m` switch is needed to tell `jar` which file is the manifest. Note that the order of `m` and `f` must match the order of `Manifest.txt` and `bot.jar`

Remember that the directory structure in the jar must match your package structure.

e.g. for `package com.me.Bot` the added file should be `com/me/Bot.class` not just `Bot.class`

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error = /

Probably fixed one of my problems though!

Comment: @Austin: In the root of your build directory, try `jar cmf Manifest.txt Bot.jar .` - This will get the correct directory structure into the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

learning how to manually build a jar is a fun thing to do once.  for the long term, however, i'd recommend learning a build tool ([ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), whatever).

Comment: I think YOU shouldn't waste your time writing such useless answers... :D Do you really think you helped? No, you didn't, at all. :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - how do you know i didn't help?  OP never chose an answer.  possibly they learned there are better ways to build jar files.

Comment: Sorry, but this kind of seeking for upvotes is a bit pathetic. (Don't U have enough reputation?) The OP asked HOW to create a JAR-file, and your answer is kind of like "I don't know how to do it, so don't do it". Congratulations, man! Answers on SO should not be like this,  it isn't helpful at all: others can also find this thread - like me - via Google and say "go to hell, man, that's not an answer". E.g. I know NetBeans and Eclipse very well, but I had a task where I had to (!) create a JAR-file "manually", found this thread, wanted to know the real answer, but found yours 1st...

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - if i was seeking upvotes, i would have given the simple answer.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - since this answer seems to offend you, i have amended the wording to something which will hopefully be more palatable.  as for the google search, didn't you find the "jar" manual page before this one?  The first hit for "java jar" for me is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: It didn't "offend" me :D :D It's just irritating (it's not the same) that someone even thinks about writing such useless answers. Why didn't you just post your thought as a COMMENT?! (This way we wouldn't debate.)
Yes, I did find the official site (and in the meantime, I solved my problem). Why does it even matter? It doesn't change the fact that you didn't answer the question at all. :) But I didn't downvote your answer (I could have, because I think it doesn't deserve any upvotes, sorry).

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - when you say i didn't answer the question, what you mean is that i didn't answer _your_ question.  while you may have a valid reason to use jar manually, most people don't.  once you have answered a few thousand questions here on SO, you will begin to realize that many people ask the _wrong_ question because they don't know any better.  you already acknowledged that i have added a lot of value to SO (my current reputation), so maybe before attacking my one answer in isolation, you should step back and think outside _your_ current problem and realize that this _is_ a valid answer.

Comment: Your reputation doesn't mean you have more valid reasons not to answer questions, only suggest not doing what the OP wants to. I find it really funny that you bring up your reputation (or number of answers) as an argument... :D So this is why I should _"step back"_? Really? :D Do not be ridiculous. If you talk about reputation, look at [Erik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5507223/517705), at least it contains useful information. And no, when I say you didn't answer the question, I mean you didn't answer _the OP's question_. Not mine. How do you even know what MY problem was? :D

Comment: Btw. you don't need to answer _"a few thousand questions here on SO"_ just to realize when the OP's question is nonsense. This question is not like that, because it may be a valid problem. I still don't get why you didn't post your thought as a COMMENT if you weren't seeking upvotes (if you didn't count on others coming and saying "yes, this question is nonsense, the OP shouldn't even have asked that, let's upvote this answer!"), but let's move on (you think it's a valid answer, I don't, even if the sentences are true ;) ). But don't refer to your reputation just to justify your statement. :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - i understand my answer upsets you, but did you even read my last comment?  your replies seem to imply you completely missed what i was saying, specifically _"you will begin to realize that many people ask the wrong question because they don't know any better"_.  I have answered many questions on SO in a similar fashion and had them accepted: "Q: i can't get X to work; A: actually you don't want to do X at all, you want to do Y".  see "the XY problem" for more details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: Let's clarify this! ;) 1. you didn't "upset" me :) 2. _YES, this is true, there are cases when the OP doesn't use the appropriate tool, because he doesn't know any better._ Maybe this is the case right now, we don't know that (the OP has disappeared). You may be right! All I'm saying is that even if you suggest using other tools - which is of course justifiable -, questions should be answered first, so that the original problem doesn't remain unsolved (even if there are better tools for doing the task). :) Others may also find the question and the answer useful. But we don't have to agree. :)